# C# generic method with 'where K : IEnumerable' and no definition for 'Select'

Tags: c#, generics

I want to create the followind generic method (it'll map my `List` of `entity objects` to the `List` of `the DTO objects`)

```
 using System.Linq;

 public static IEnumerable<T> ToDTOList<T, K>(dynamic entity) where K : IEnumerable
 {
     return ((K)entity).Select(x => (T)DTOsMapper.ToDTO<T>(x));
 }
```

> 'K' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method
>   'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'K' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It's absolutely right - there's no `Select` method on `IEnumerable`. There *is* on `IEnumerable<T>`, the generic type...

Comment: There *is* however, a `Cast<T>` on plain IEnumerable. *And* you can also adjust your constraint to IEnumerable<K> (or whatever the sequence type is.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I changed that method to

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ToDTOList<T, K>(IEnumerable<K> entity)
{
    return entity.Select(x => (T)DTOsMapper.ToDTO<T>(x));
}
```